# What is the very last place where you can execute logic in a Windows executable?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

In my application, I want to execute logic at the very last moment.  The later, the better.

The reason for this is that I keep track of certain elements in my application (data structures, resources, ...), and at the end of the application, a routine looks at these elements and reports if they were not correctly closed, freed, deleted, ...

Until now, we did this using several tricks.

The first trick was to overrule the _heap_term function of the C run time (and some other functions as well in the C Run Time).  The advantage was that this worked very well, but was limited to applications in which the CRT was statically linked in.

The second trick was to define a global variable like this:

```
#pragma init_seg(lib)
GlobalApplicationManager s_globalApplicationManager;
```

The pragma makes sure that this global variable is constructed before all other global variables, and - more important - that it is destructed after all other global variables.
This way, we can put the checking logic in the destructor of this class.

Problem is that starting from Windows 7 the destructor is not called anymore in some situations.  At this moment it is not clear what influences this, but we are sure that it is not called if we make a successful Oracle connection in our application.

What other tricks are there to execute code as late as possible in an application?

Comment: If globals cause some problems, perhaps the nicest solution is to refactor your code and not use globals at all.

Comment: agreed. If you're having trouble managing the lifetime of your resources, coming up with *more* hacks, making the lifetime even more unmanageable hardly seems like the right way to go.

Comment: @ereOn, I agree, but globals are not the only problem. What I want is a built-in check of the internal data structures at the end of the application (including, and probably most important, whether all memory has been freed correctly). Before Windows 7, if our application had still memory allocated at the very end, the developer/tester/internaluser was notified of this automatically. This almost guaranteed that every developer was notified immediately of any memory leaks. No external tools were needed, since the checks were built-in.

Comment: @Patrick: No offense, but I believe this is the wrong approach. The program **should not** leak. If it does, fix it, using tools designed for that purpose. Rewriting and embedding such a tool in your software makes it bigger, probably slower, and harder to maintain. How will you deal with segmentation faults ? Will you embed a debugger as well ?

Comment: @ereOn, well, in fact I do, almost.  After having read John Robbins' terrific "Debugging Windows Applications" book, I introduced a crash handler that used the dbghelp.dll logic to write a minidump file that can be sent by the customer to me.  Stricly spoken, I don't have to do it, but it helps in finding problems in an easier way, without relying on external tools (imaging telling your customer that you he has to reproduce the problem while you have your debugger attached).  Although external tools have their advantages, having certain things built-in can also be very useful.

Comment: @ereOn.  Also: no offense taken.  Every comment is welcome.

Comment: @Patrick: I guess your software is meant to be setup on customers computers on which you have no control. If so, I understand why you did this. I admit there is nothing worse than relying on a customer to resolve a bug. However, I still believe that a correct code design, easier to maintain, is preferable over a software that has bugs and tools to report them. Have you ever considered how much time you spent on the tools used to find the bugs instead of spending it on the bugs themselves ? Does it really worth it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/ENTRYPOINT`.  In your custom entry point, call the CRT entry point and then your final logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should try to refactor your code:
Any member variable should be destructed in the relevant class destructor.

for global variables, you may define a destruction function `void func()`, and call `atexit(func)` upon initialization.

Comment: In theory you are right: the class destructor should cleanup its own things.  Problem is that part of the application is still in plain C.  And we want the extra checks to notify developers if they forgot to cleanup certain things.  Hence the checking logic at the end of the application.  We also considered using atexit, but apparently, if the global variables are not cleaned up, the atexit function isn't being called either.  Nevertheless, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of sections defined by the CRT to which you can add your own calls with `#pragma`. By using the right name you can add code at various points of the initialisation and shutdown process. However the names are not easy to find.

Check out "crt0dat.c" in the CRT source installed with VS2010 for some of the names.

Answer (score 1):

You could place your logic in a `DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)` function in a helper DLL. This happens even after the EXE's entry point has returned (assuming that even returns - it might not due to `TerminateThread`) so it's more reliable and later than Ben Voigt's earlier suggestion.

Don't assume you can do too much, though. It's pretty much the very last place where you can execute logic, but you can't rely on other DLL's being present anymore. That's the entire point of DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. You can only count on Kernel32.DLL being left.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass your window/application a custom message after the call to ShowWindow ?